# WP - Button for creating timestamp in db

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Heller,
  I'm working on a plugin and I've just totally hit a wall. I'm wanting to create a plugin, if you will, for wordpress where the user that's logged in would be able to navigate to, select an option from a dropdown menu, hit a button and have an entry added to a db. I'm wanting two databases created on the initial button click and then every button click after would append to the database that corresponds to the current user and the option selected. So, for example let's say I have Joe Smith. He logs in and navigates to, let's call it "Time Clock" in the wp menu. Upon loading, he has the option to select the location he is at and click, clock in. If this is first time "clocking in", wp creates two databases, one for "joe_smith" that would record a timestamp of when he hit the button and also the location he was at when he hit it. The other database would be named after the location and would record the date and time and who the user was who was at the location. After that, if Joe came back later in the day and was at the same location and selected the same properties, it would add another row of in "joe_smith" database and another row in "a_location"s row as well. If he changed locations it would still add to "joe_smith"s database but would create/append to the new locations databse "new_location".

Ideally I'd like to have the locations in a dropdown menu and that is populated by another db that houses all the location information and is editable by the admin. Am I on the right track with my thinking about how to set this up best? Anyone have any pointers or the ability to spit this code out easily? Haha. I've been doing my best at learning the wp system and how to create plugins and my deadline is coming up quickly to have something that functions. Thank you in advance to anyone that can help me on this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you split up the logic for *creating the database* and whatever needs to happen when the user *clicks the button*. In particular:

1. create a **table** when the plugin is activated (use [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)). [More information about standard practices for this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).
2. make your plugin store the available *locations* in WordPress' options table ([use its API for managing it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) and create [an appropriate options page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) for your plugin to manage them).
3. when the plugin is uninstalled (not deactivated), drop the table to leave everything as it was (using [`register_uninstall_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook)).
4. when the user *clicks the button*, add an entry to your table (that will obviously need to - at least - contain a timestamp, the userid and the location).